# Spring Boot Mapping Resource of a sub folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mapping-resources

I'm trying to map a sub folder of my resources to server index.html and images associated.

My resources are located inside folder resources/a/b/c. (ie resources/a/b/c/index.html)

I want this html page to be accessible from my root path (http://localhost:8080/index.html).

I'm extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to configure the mapping. I tried several path but nothing worked so far.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
   {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
            "classpath:/resources/a/b/c",
            "classpath:/a/b/c",
            "/resources/a/b/c",
            "/a/b/c",
            "classpath:resources/a/b/c",
            "classpath:a/b/c",
            "resources/a/b/c",
            "a/b/c");
   }
}
```

Can someone give me some guidance on this?

Thanks

Comment: try adding redirect `@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("index.html", "/a/b/c/index.html");
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
>   called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
>   the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

So if you have:

```
src
└── main
    └── resources
        └── static
            ├── images
            │       └── image.png
            └── index.html
```

You can access your resources via :

```
http://localhost:8080/ (index.html)
http://localhost:8080/index.html  
http://localhost:8080/images/image.png
```

Notice that you must not add static in the url and must restart the server when adding a new resource.

Comment: I'll be honest I have the same problem - spring seems happy to server content from 'public' but not from, say, 'public/images'

Comment: @Andy: Is your URL just the sub-folder without any specification of file? (e.g. `http://localhost/subfolder/`). Spring Boot will only auto-serve an `index.html` file from the top-level folder, e.g. from `src/main/resources/static` in this example, not for a sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot servers static content resources under the root path.
You can change it by setting ***spring.resources.static-locations*** configuration property like this:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/a/b/c/
```